# Improve repeated for loops in a more pythonic way based on an object existing ot nor properties

Tags: python

I have an Object(retrieved from a database), with multiple attributes:

```
db_obj.default_attr= "textdefault"
 db_obj.additional = {
    "alpha": "texta",
    "beta": "textb",   
    "gama": "textg",
    "teta": "textt",
     ...
}
 db_obj.name: "some_name"
 ....
```

`additional` property is also an Object can be **empty/null/not having all values**, in db is null or json

And `types` an Array: `["alpha", "gama", ...]`

---

I have the following function, that is called:

```
set_att(obj=db_object, types=types)
```

I need to create a new Object based on `types` array:

Example of properties:

```
  new_obj.alpha = "texta"
  new_obj.gama =  "textdefault"  # because gama was not found in additional
```

I defined the function:

```
def set_att(db_obj=None, types=None):

 new_obj = types.SimpleNamespace()

try:

  add = db_obj.getattr(additional)

  # cycle thru types, and assign the value from the db_obj if exist or the     default_attr value
  for item_type in types: 
     try:
        setattr(new_obj, item_type, add.getattr(item_type))
      except AttributeError: 
         setattr(new_obj, item_type, obj.getattr(default_attr))   

 # if there is not addtional I still set default for type
except AttributeError:
    for item_type in types: 
         setattr(new_obj, item_type, obj.getattr(default_attr)
```

It looks naive, and I'm looking for a more pythonic option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hasattr` to check if the object has an attribute instead of catching the AttributeException. It will make the code easier to read because it is explicitly handling the expected case of the attribute not being present. Using an exception makes it seem as if it is an error case.

```
 for item_type in types:
     if hasattr(add, item_type):
         value = getattr(add, item_type) 
     else:
         value = getattr(obj, default_attr)
     setattr(new_obj, item_type, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class like this to access the array keys as object properties

```
class CustomDict(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super(CustomDict, self).__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return super(CustomDict, self).__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return self.build(default)

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, orig):
        if isinstance(orig, basestring):
            return orig
        if isinstance(orig, Sequence):
            return [cls.build(item) for item in orig]
        elif isinstance(orig, Mapping):
            new = cls()
            for key, value in orig.iteritems():
                new[key] = cls.build(value)
            return new
        return orig
```

Use like this::

```
additional = {
    "alpha": "texta",
    "beta": "textb",   
    "gama": "textg",
    "teta": "textt",
}
new=CustomDict(additional)
```

Then you can acces to the attributes :

```
print(new.alpha) # print texta
print(new.xyz)   # print None
```